# Differing results from same select statement

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have this query

```
SELECT regexp_replace(pn, '([\\W]*)', '') as pn,
       min(date) as date, 
       count(date) as num_days, 
       if((month in (1,3,5,7,8,10,12) and count(date) < 31) 
           or (month in (4,6,9,11) and count(date) < 30)
           or (month = 2 and count(date) < 28), 
           "MISSING", 
           "COMPLETE") as missingORcomplete
FROM `playground-216119.ben.demand_count_daily` dcd
JOIN `playground-216119.ben.CALENDAR_DIMENSION` cd on dcd.date = cd.date_id
where pn = 'MPU6500'
group by year,month,pn
order by date
```

And its output is

[image]

But when I put `` create or replace table `missing_days` as `` in front of that query

```
create or replace table `playground-216119.ben.missing_days` as
SELECT regexp_replace(pn, '([\\W]*)', '') as pn,
       min(date) as date, 
       count(date) as num_days, 
       if((month in (1,3,5,7,8,10,12) and count(date) < 31) 
           or (month in (4,6,9,11) and count(date) < 30)
           or (month = 2 and count(date) < 28), 
           "MISSING", 
           "COMPLETE") as missingORcomplete
FROM `playground-216119.ben.demand_count_daily` dcd
JOIN `playground-216119.ben.CALENDAR_DIMENSION` cd on dcd.date = cd.date_id
group by year,month,pn
order by date, on
```

then query the results of the table creation with

`` SELECT * FROM `missing_days` where pn = 'MPU6500' order by date ``

the output is

[image]

I know in the first one I have the where clause, but that was just to show you how it should look, and then in the second one I remove it to create all of the other part number instances as well. I have no idea why the information within my table is different than the information that I get in the select statement. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please post both the complete query.

Comment: Maybe because you have changed the dataset and calculations are on revised data.

Comment: @rtenha, I am grouping by these because there are multiple years in the database and multiple months within each year. I don't group by missingORcomplete because it is already an aggregate.

Comment: as June said, are you sure the data is not changed between your select statement and create or replace table statement? This should be the case when your data is changed or your create or replace table query has changed. Please provide you create replace query as well. Just to ensure that case is ruled out.